# spark disable support for quotes

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
val dfInput = spark.read
  .option("delimiter", "\u0001")
  .csv(file)
```

By default, it is reading quotes(ignoring delimiters between quotes).  I could add `.option("quote", "\u0000")` as a work around, but I am looking for a more permanent solution, as that is a hacky fix, to not read in any quotes.  Is something like this supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like there is anything built in for that yet, you can see the current features [here](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv#features).

Comment: That link is obsolete... Only applies to Spark 1.x.